# How do I pipe into printf?

Tags: bash, pipe, printf, zsh

I'm going nuts trying to understand what is the problem with this simple example (zsh or bash):

```sh
echo -n "6842" | printf "%'d"
```

The output is `0`... why though? I'd like the output to be `6,842`

Thanks in advance, I've had no luck for an hour now using google trying to figure this out...!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`printf` doesn't read arguments to format from standard input, but from the command line directly. For example, this works:

```
$ printf "%'d" 6842
6,842
```

You can convert output of a command to command-line arguments using command substitution:

```
$ printf "%'d" $(echo -n 6842)
6,842
```

If you want to invoke `printf` inside a pipeline, you can use `xargs` to read input and execute `printf` with the appropriate arguments:

```
echo -n "6842" | xargs printf "%'d"
```

Answer (score 3):

`printf` does not format data passed to it on standard input; it takes a set of arguments, the first of which is the format, and the remainder are the values to display.

Luckily, this is exactly what `xargs` is for; to quote the manual:

> xargs - build and execute command lines from standard input

So instead of piping to `printf` directly, you can pipe to `xargs`, and tell it to run `printf` for you with the given arguments. In short:

```
echo -n "6842" | xargs printf "%'d"
```

Comment: Thank you as well, glad to see the consensus ;)